Does CloudAnt support ES6 functions or not?
The CloudAnt server says it is using CouchDB 3.4.2, and ES6 support was added to CouchDB in  version 3.0..., but I am not able to use fat arrow function syntax in the online view editor for my database. Is this a limitation of the editor, or of CloudAnt?
for example:
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  const uniqWith = (arr, fn) =>
    arr.filter(
        (element, index) => arr.findIndex((step) => fn(element, step)) === index
    );
  return uniqWith(values, (a, b) => a.moves === b.moves )
}

I get an error saying this is not a function.

Which is the exact place in that code where you get the error? Is all that code needed to get that error?

I actually don't see a syntax error in the editor; but when saving it tells me that it's "not a function".  A simpler example:  function(...){ const foo=()=>1; return foo() }
